# Angular Routing with Asp.net mvc areas and cshtml not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My layout.cshtml contains:

```
    <li><a href="#/User">User</a></li>
<div ng-view></div>
```

This is my controller:

[image]

and its action methods:

public class UserController : Controller

```
{
    // GET: Admin/Default
    BMS2Entities _db = new BMS2Entities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var emp = _db.AspNetUsers.ToList();
        return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And index.cshtml and index.js file inside:

[image]

index.js contains server call to usercontroller inside admin area:

app.controller('userController', function ($scope, $http) {

```
$http({ method: 'Get', url: 'Areas/Admin/User/Index' })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.depts = response.data;
            });
```

});

and finally myapp.js file for routing:

var app = angular.module('myAppS', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

```
$routeProvider.when('/User', {
    templateUrl: 'Areas/Admin/Views/User/Index.cshtml',
    controller: 'userController'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

});

but the codes are not working and it does not display cshtml and shows
https://localhost:44382/Common/Home#/User in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$routeProvider.when('/User', {
    templateUrl: 'Areas/Admin/Views/User/Index.cshtml',
    controller: 'userController'
});

You need to prefix root path in templateUrl and same thing in while calling controller's action.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write ng-app directive in layout.cshtml?
And I think the syntax for  tag should be like

```
<a href="/#/User">User</a>
```

Hope this Helps!